# Amazon AWS Gateway API with WebSocket

Tags: amazon-web-services, websocket, real-time

Does Amazon AWS Gateway API be used to broadcast the message to the thousands of users simultaneously using WebSocket ?

For Example Client A chrome is sending a message in a grp of 1000s approx. So by sending it one by one there is latency among the users so, can we emit broadcast from AWS Gateway WebSocket

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

not out of the box, but you can achieve that

API Gateway WebSocket API [requires a connection id to send a message](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/ApiGatewayManagementApi.html#postToConnection-property),

```js
var params = {
  ConnectionId: '',
  Data: ''
};
apigatewaymanagementapi.postToConnection(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack);
  else     console.log(data);          
});
```

because of that, what you can do is persist all connection id to a DynamoDB table on the **$connect** event and broadcast a message to all ids when needed,

for example, using javascript:

```js
let apigateway = new AWS.ApiGatewayManagementApi();
let ddb = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient(...);
let params = {
    TableName: 'ConnectionIds'
};
let records = await documentClient.scan(params).promise();
let messages = records.map(item => {
    return apigateway
        .postToConnection({
            ConnectionId: item.id,
            Data: 'My Message'
        }).promise()
});
await Promise.all(messages);
```

Comment: This Solution is insufficient if my app is large for example 1000+ members and group, it will send message one by one this would bring latency in the group

Comment: is not send one by one, promise.all awaits all promises executing in parallel form records.map, it is up to api gateway to delivery it, for latency you would be relying in the aws infrastructure to push the messages... make sure you are familiar with the limits on the websocket https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/limits.html#apigateway-execution-service-websocket-limits-table